# Get all value including null value

Tags: php, laravel

In my coordinator_status column, there are values and null. When I run this code it only returns the ones with value only. I want to get null values too but I don't know how.

```
$coordetails = DB::table('courselist')
                        ->join('users','users.id','=','courselist.coordinator')
                        ->join('status','status.id','=','courselist.coordinator_status')
                        ->select('courselist.id','users.name','status.status')
                        ->where('courselist.faculty_id','=',$facultyid)
                        ->get();
```

Comment: Have you tried left join?

Comment: This isn't a Laravel problem, it is a basic SQL problem (which has been resolved many times on Stack Overflow over the years).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do this, you should use [leftJoin](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#left-join-right-join-clause):

```
$coordetails = DB::table('courselist')
                        ->leftJoin('users','users.id','=','courselist.coordinator')
                        ->leftJoin('status','status.id','=','courselist.coordinator_status')
                        ->select('courselist.id','users.name','status.status')
                        ->where('courselist.faculty_id','=',$facultyid)
                        ->get();
```

The `LEFT JOIN` keyword returns all records from the left table , and the matching records from the right table if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

according to me if you want to get null and value both data you have to use **left join** instead of join

you can find documentation on laravel site [join in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins)

if you want to get courselist with joined user

```
DB::table('courselist')
->select('courselist.id','users.name','status.status')
->join('users','users.id','=','courselist.coordinator')
->leftJoin('status','status.id','=','courselist.coordinator_status')
->where('courselist.faculty_id','=',$facultyid)
->get();
```

if you want to get all courselist data without user relation then

```
DB::table('courselist')
->leftJoin('users','users.id','=','courselist.coordinator')
->leftJoin('status','status.id','=','courselist.coordinator_status')
->select('courselist.id','users.name','status.status')
->where('courselist.faculty_id','=',$facultyid)
->get();
```

and sql query will be like

SELECT *
FROM testDb.course
LEFT JOIN testDb.status ON testDb.course.status=testDb.status.id;

Comment: Wasn't this advice already given nearly an hour earlier?